# jQuery Draggable Containment Overflow Hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, draggable

This is about dragging wider element than its parent (overflow: hidden). Parent's width and overflow options are fixed, cannot be changed.

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <p class="text">The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.</p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
  position:relative;
  width:300px;
  height:50px;
  background:#ccc;
  overflow:hidden; // be careful, changing to overflow-x:hidden breaks the answer
}
.text {
  position:absolute;
  top:7px;
  margin:0;
  width:1000px;
  font-size:30px;
}
```

jQuery

```
$('.text').draggable({
  axis: 'x',
})
```

Modify this demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/jeafgilbert/LtkkzccL/

So that we can only drag the sentence **without making spaces before or after the sentence**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check the current position of draggable element in the `drag` callback and then override the position if it is outside of the bounds.

In other words, if the left positioning is greater than `0`, override the left positioning and set it back to `0` so that it can never exceed `0`. If the width of the draggable element minus the width of the parent element is less than the left positioning, override the left positioning to set it back to the offset width.

[**Updated Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/cz6ycL6w/)

```js
$('.text').draggable({
  axis: 'x',
  drag: function(event, ui) {
    var left = ui.position.left,
        offsetWidth = ($(this).width() - $(this).parent().width()) * -1;

    if (left > 0) {
      ui.position.left = 0;
    }
    if (offsetWidth > left) {
      ui.position.left = offsetWidth;
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #ccc;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 7px;
  margin: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <p class="text">The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, Josh Crozier!

Comment: Btw, force dragging the text to the right makes text jump to the end. I added parent's width to see it easier (https://jsfiddle.net/jeafgilbert/vom7tpo9/1/).